# Stuck On edges horizontally c# unity character controller Capsule

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here i am with another question....

since last time, i got my answer within a day, and cant find anything on google...

so rn, this is my movement code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class FunctionalTransform
{ 
    public Transform PlayerDirection;   
}
[System.Serializable] 
public class PlayerValues
{
    public float PlayerHeight = 2f;
    public float PlayerRadius = 0.5f;
}
[System.Serializable] 
public class Unit
{
    [Header("Physics")]
    public float GForce = 9.80665f;

    [Header("Calculation")]
    [HideInInspector] public float SpeedUnitConversion = 3.6f;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class MovementSetting
{

    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] public MovementSpeed MovementSpeeds;

    [Header("Physics")]
    [SerializeField] public MovementForce MovementForces;
}
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MovementSpeed
    {
        [Header("Settings")]
        public float WalkSpeed = 5.1f;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MovementForce
    {
        [Header("Forces")]
        public float AccelSpeed = 5f;
        public float BreakSpeed = 4f;
    }
[System.Serializable]
public class GroundRelated
{ 
    
}
public class MovmentUltimate : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Transforms")]
    [SerializeField] FunctionalTransform FunctionalTransforms; 

    [Header("Physics")]
    [SerializeField] Unit Units;
    
    [Header("Player Body")]
    [SerializeField] PlayerValues PlayerBody;

    [Header("Movement Settings")]
    [SerializeField] MovementSetting MovementSettings;

    GroundRelated Ground;

    public float TargetMoveSpeed = 5f;

    // Movement
    float CurrentMoveX;
    float CurrentMoveZ;

    float TargetMoveX;
    float TargetMoveZ;

    public Vector3 MoveInputDir;
    public Vector3 MoveTerrainDir;
    public Vector3 MoveWallDir;
    public Vector3 MoveDirNormalizedOutput;
    public Vector3 CurrentMovementDirection; 

    public Vector3 WallHitDir;

    public bool WallHitBool;
    bool OnSlope;

    float SnapRange = 0.1f;
    
    float CurrentAccelSpeed;
    float CurrentBreakSpeed;

    Vector3 TargetPos;

    public bool OnCollisionBox;

    void Update()
    {
        MovementInputs();
        SetSpeed();
        MovementCalculation();
        Verticality();
        MoveOutput();    
    }
        void MovementInputs()
        { 
            DirectionalMovementInput();
        }
            void DirectionalMovementInput()
            { 
                // Move X - Horizontal
                if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveX = -TargetMoveSpeed / Units.SpeedUnitConversion;

                    if(CurrentMoveX > TargetMoveX)
                    { 
                        if(CurrentMoveX > 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveX -= Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                        }
                        else if(CurrentMoveX <= 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveX -= Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                        }           
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveX <= TargetMoveX)
                    {
                        CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
                    }
                }
                else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveX = TargetMoveSpeed / Units.SpeedUnitConversion;

                    if(CurrentMoveX < TargetMoveX)
                    { 
                        if(CurrentMoveX < 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveX += Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                        }
                        else if(CurrentMoveX >= 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveX += Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                        }                
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveX >= TargetMoveX)
                    {
                        CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
                    }
                }
                else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveX = 0f;

                    if(CurrentMoveX > 0.1f)
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveX -= Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveX < -0.1f)
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveX += Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveX = TargetMoveX;
                    }
                }

                // Move Z - Vertical
                if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveZ = -TargetMoveSpeed / Units.SpeedUnitConversion;

                    if(CurrentMoveZ > TargetMoveZ)
                    { 
                        if(CurrentMoveZ > 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveZ -= Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                        }
                        else if(CurrentMoveZ <= 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveZ -= Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                        }           
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveZ <= TargetMoveZ)
                    {
                        CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
                    }
                }
                else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveZ = TargetMoveSpeed / Units.SpeedUnitConversion;

                    if(CurrentMoveZ < TargetMoveZ)
                    { 
                        if(CurrentMoveZ < 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveZ += Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                        }
                        else if(CurrentMoveZ >= 0f)
                        { 
                            CurrentMoveZ += Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                        }                
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveZ >= TargetMoveZ)
                    {
                        CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
                    }
                }
                else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 0f)
                { 
                    TargetMoveZ = 0f;

                    if(CurrentMoveZ > SnapRange)
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveZ -= Units.GForce * (CurrentAccelSpeed + CurrentBreakSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    else if(CurrentMoveZ < -SnapRange)
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveZ += Units.GForce * CurrentAccelSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        CurrentMoveZ = TargetMoveZ;
                    }
                }        
            }
        
        void SetSpeed()
        { 
            CurrentAccelSpeed = MovementSettings.MovementForces.AccelSpeed;
            CurrentBreakSpeed = MovementSettings.MovementForces.BreakSpeed;            
        }
        void MovementCalculation()
        { 
            MoveInputDir = FunctionalTransforms.PlayerDirection.forward * CurrentMoveZ + FunctionalTransforms.PlayerDirection.right * CurrentMoveX;

            RaycastHit TerrainHit;
            
            TerrainDetection();

            void TerrainDetection()
            { 
                if(Physics.SphereCast(transform.position + new Vector3(0, (-PlayerBody.PlayerHeight / 2f) + PlayerBody.PlayerRadius), PlayerBody.PlayerRadius, Vector3.down, out TerrainHit))
                {
                    if(TerrainHit.normal != Vector3.up)
                    { 
                        OnSlopeFunction();         
                        OnSlope = true;                                         
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        NotOnSlopeFunction();
                        OnSlope = false;        
                    }
                }
                else
                { 
                    NotOnSlopeFunction();
                    OnSlope = false;
                }            
            }

            // Follow Terrain/Slopes

            void OnSlopeFunction()
            { 
                MoveTerrainDir = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(MoveInputDir, TerrainHit.normal);             
            }
            void NotOnSlopeFunction()
            { 
                MoveTerrainDir = MoveInputDir;
            }

            NormalizeMovementDir();

            void NormalizeMovementDir()
            { 
                Vector3 MoveDirNormal = MoveTerrainDir.normalized;
                        MoveDirNormal = new Vector3(Mathf.Abs(MoveDirNormal.x), Mathf.Abs(MoveDirNormal.y), Mathf.Abs(MoveDirNormal.z));
                        MoveDirNormalizedOutput = new Vector3(MoveTerrainDir.x * MoveDirNormal.x, MoveTerrainDir.y * MoveDirNormal.y, MoveTerrainDir.z * MoveDirNormal.z);
                 
            }
            
            MoveDirAllow();           

            void MoveDirAllow()
            {
                RaycastHit EdgeHit;

                TargetPos = MoveInputDir * Time.deltaTime;

                Vector3 LookDirPos = (transform.position + TargetPos) - transform.position;

                Quaternion RayDirRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(LookDirPos, Vector3.up);

                // Angle Detection
                Vector3 BoxSize = new Vector3(PlayerBody.PlayerRadius * 2f, PlayerBody.PlayerHeight * 0.99f, PlayerBody.PlayerRadius * 2f);

                if(Physics.OverlapCapsule(transform.position + TargetPos + new Vector3(0, -(PlayerBody.PlayerHeight / 2.01f) * PlayerBody.PlayerRadius, 0), transform.position + TargetPos + new Vector3(0, (PlayerBody.PlayerHeight / 2f) - PlayerBody.PlayerRadius, 0), PlayerBody.PlayerRadius).Length == 0)
                {                                                
                    if(Physics.BoxCast(transform.position + TargetPos, BoxSize / 4f, RayDirRot * Vector3.forward, out EdgeHit, RayDirRot, PlayerBody.PlayerRadius / 2f))
                    { 
                        RaycastHit WallMoveHit;

                        OnCollisionBox = true;

                        Vector3 OriginPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, EdgeHit.point.y, transform.position.z);

                        Vector3 WallHitDirPos = EdgeHit.point - OriginPos;
                        Quaternion WallHitDirRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(WallHitDirPos, Vector3.up);

                        Physics.Raycast(OriginPos, WallHitDirRot * Vector3.forward, out WallMoveHit);
                        Debug.DrawLine(OriginPos, EdgeHit.point, Color.red, 1);

                        Vector3 WallMoveDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(MoveDirNormalizedOutput, WallMoveHit.normal);

                        CurrentMovementDirection = WallMoveDirection * Time.deltaTime;

                        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, EdgeHit.point, Color.red, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        DefaultInput();


                        OnCollisionBox = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                { 
                    StopMovement();

                    OnCollisionBox = false;
                }

                void DefaultInput()
                { 
                    CurrentMovementDirection = MoveDirNormalizedOutput * Time.deltaTime;                         
                }

                void StopMovement()
                { 
                    CurrentMovementDirection = Vector3.zero;                 
                }
            }
        }
        void Verticality()
        {

        }
        void MoveOutput()
        { 
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position + CurrentMovementDirection, 1f / Time.deltaTime);
        }
        void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            Vector3 BoxSize = new Vector3(PlayerBody.PlayerRadius * 2f, PlayerBody.PlayerHeight * 0.99f, PlayerBody.PlayerRadius * 2f);
            

            Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position + transform.forward * 0f, BoxSize);
        }
}
```

[now this is my problem...](https://youtu.be/x9BHyJKWb4A)

[seems to me like this is the problem...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcps3.png)

might need to add where the 2 rays connect as an offset?

trying to move diagonally next to the block, i would assume idd just follow the wall, but there seems to be an issue regarding to that since the collider goes into the wall..

EDIT 1: i tried to dig deeper into the solution, just need a practical way to excecute it... cant be a raycast, since i cant always be sure at what height the object is... but for my own work and thinking, i got this.

[image: What for me seems to be the solution... just dont know how to excecute it.]

so... i tried some more, and ended up with 2 code projects..

Collision Test Code:

```
[Header("Player Objects")]
public GameObject PlayerDirection;
public GameObject PlayerObject;

[Header("Player Properties")]
public float PlayerHeight = 2f;
public float PlayerRadius = 0.5f;

Vector3 PlayerSize;

RaycastHit EdgeHit;
Vector3 EdgeHitPosition;

Vector3 DirectionSloped;

Vector3 CurrentOutput;

void Update()
{
    RaycastHit SlopeHit;

    Vector3 InputDirection = PlayerDirection.transform.forward * Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") + PlayerDirection.transform.right * Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if(Physics.SphereCast(transform.position + Vector3.up * (-(PlayerHeight / 2f) + PlayerRadius), PlayerRadius, Vector3.down, out SlopeHit))
    { 
        if(SlopeHit.normal != Vector3.up)
        {
            DirectionSloped = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(InputDirection, SlopeHit.normal);
        }
        else
        { 
            DirectionSloped = InputDirection;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        DirectionSloped = InputDirection;    
    }

    PlayerSize = new Vector3(PlayerRadius * 2f, PlayerHeight, PlayerRadius * 2f);

    Vector3 CurrentPosition = PlayerObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 FuturePosition = CurrentPosition + InputDirection * Time.deltaTime;

    bool CanMoveToFuturePos()
    { 
        if(Physics.OverlapCapsule(FuturePosition + Vector3.up * (-(PlayerHeight / 2.01f) + PlayerRadius), FuturePosition + Vector3.up * ((PlayerHeight / 2f) + PlayerRadius), PlayerRadius).Length == 0)
        {   
            return true;
        }            
        else
        { 
            return false;    
        }
    }

    bool RayHitEdge()
    {
        if(CanMoveToFuturePos())
        { 
            if(Physics.BoxCast(FuturePosition, PlayerSize / 4f, transform.forward, out EdgeHit, transform.rotation, PlayerRadius / 1.99f))
            { 
                return true;     
            }
            else if(Physics.BoxCast(FuturePosition, PlayerSize / 4f, transform.right, out EdgeHit, transform.rotation, PlayerRadius / 1.99f))
            { 
                return true;  
            }
            else if(Physics.BoxCast(FuturePosition, PlayerSize / 4f, -transform.forward, out EdgeHit, transform.rotation, PlayerRadius / 1.99f))
            { 
                return true;    
            }
            else if(Physics.BoxCast(FuturePosition, PlayerSize / 4f, -transform.right, out EdgeHit, transform.rotation, PlayerRadius / 1.99f))
            { 
                return true;  
            }
            else
            { 
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(RayHitEdge())
    { 
        EdgeOutput();
    }
    else
    { 

        if(CanMoveToFuturePos())
        { 
            DefaultOutput();                    
        }
        else
        { 
            ResetOutput();     
        }
    }

    void DefaultOutput()
    { 
        CurrentOutput = DirectionSloped;
    }

    void EdgeOutput()
    { 
        RaycastHit WallMoveHit;
        Vector3 OriginPos = new Vector3(PlayerObject.transform.position.x, EdgeHit.point.y, PlayerObject.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 WallHitDirPos = EdgeHit.point - OriginPos;
        Quaternion WallHitDirRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(WallHitDirPos, Vector3.up);
        Physics.Raycast(OriginPos, WallHitDirRot * Vector3.forward, out WallMoveHit);

        Vector3 EdgeMovement = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(DirectionSloped, WallMoveHit.normal);
        CurrentOutput = EdgeMovement;
    }

    void ResetOutput()
    { 
        CurrentOutput = Vector3.zero;    
    }

    MoveOutput();

    void MoveOutput()
    { 
        transform.position += CurrentOutput.normalized * Time.deltaTime;     
    }
}
```

}

and updated the old code, to match my new one...

i move along the wallvector now... but still get stuck in/on edges...

will update with a youtube video soon.

Comment: If you already have a capsule collider anyway .. why exactly do "manual" `OverlapCapsule` checks? Why not rather simply rely on the physics system and move your object through a `Rigibody` component?

Comment: because im gonna run it without the player actually having a collider... i do all the speed measurements, accel and deaccel calculation by hand... to make it as 1:1 with real life as possible... this ended up being the most ideal solution since i can just do the m/s output and convert it to u/s, but at that point the point of a rigidbody is already kinda invalid cause idd just set the velocity, but i have added extra steps like getting the component, freezerotation and all that other bs, at this point my collider is not even active, its just for visuals...

Comment: but im still kinda new to unity, so im kinda in my fuck around and find out phase. so this is also kinda a learning experiment for me...

Comment: ah I didn't see it was disabled in your video. I think the main issue might be that you only clamp whether you can move or not. So if the movement is so fast that you would clip a bit into the objects you do not allow move at all instead of just clamping to the maximum movement without clipping - rigidbody would do all this for you + already is using a physics engine from NVidia which I would expect more 1:1 to real life than anything you can come up with on your own ;)

Comment: its actually really slow. but its touching, its not clipping in. the problem is actually that if the capsule touches the edge, the next position, is actually into the wall.. since the outer edge of the capsule, would actually go in to the block while the other parts of the capsule are still actually in a legit position... so i kinda need a way to a apply an offset of some sorts.. it has nothing to do with speed... i know how to use a rigidbody, but no matter how i used friction 
drag or whatever, it never got me the right result..

Comment: although i do agree, yes its a better physics engine... there are just some things about it that i dislike for use as a character controller. but i dont really like the character controller either, so i wondered how much work it would take to do it from scratch. so thats what i started doing. and well except for the base, i still got this bug to fix horizontally, and have been messing around with going vertically.. but want this foolproof first. seems to completely work, but again... edges.

Comment: `cant be a raycast, since i cant always be sure at what height the object is` what about a [`CapsuleCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CapsuleCast.html)? It would give you further info about where exactly it hits something -> from there you could calculate again how far you can move the object using your collider and [`ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html)

Comment: i tried it... cant seem to figure it it out... the solution doesnt seem to work (for now)... and is giving me either no or really weird results... but will try around some more, and see if i get anything... im also thinking, that i can shoot a raycast from bottom to top... see where that hits. take that y and shoot a raycast from that height...

Comment: so the raycast idea failed, i got the capsule cast idea to work, but it looks really janky since i just get pushed to the side while moving into a edge... i tried moving along the raycast normal... but it doesnt seem to work propely either...

Comment: also the detection of capsulecast is horrible, while experimenting tried to get a raycasthit, and do: WallHitDir = Vector3.Cross(WallHit.normal, transform.up); &                 MoveWallDir = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(MoveTerrainDir, WallHitDir); but this also did not end up working well.

Comment: So i kinda got the raycast idea to work, with normalizing my movement with a raycast wall hit, but... it does not seem to work with a capsule cast... gonna update my post with the data soon...

Comment: Well, no update done, since it sucked, but got your idea to work perfectly for my stair movement, so saved me some time i guess tho, thanks! also found that what i want is called, collide and slide...